# Popup containt become blank at the time of moving the popup positions by selecting popup header

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, popup, devexpress

I am opening the view into popup control by using ContentUrl property of popup. 
But when I try to move the positions of popup by selecting popup header. popup containt become blank still I am moving or selected the popup header. Same issue is present for in devexpress demo which was provided online.

I refered the following demo of devexpress popup controal
http://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxDockAndPopupsDemos/PopupControl/ContentUrl

I have written the following code
HomeController

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult SendProduct(string rowId)
        {
            Product objProduct = new Product();
            return View(objProduct);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SendProduct(Product objProduct)
        {
            return View(objProduct);
        }
    }
```

Product model

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Index.chtml

```
   @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@using DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI
@using DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView
@using UI.Infrastructure.Resources;
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnBeginCallback(s, e) {
        e.customArgs["rowId"] = 123;
    }
    function Click() {
        pcSendProduct.PerformCallback();
        if (!pcSendProduct.IsVisible())
            pcSendProduct.Show();
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:Click()">Enumalate menu click</a>
<div>
   @Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
                                   {
                                       settings.Name = "btnSend";
                                       settings.Width = 80;
                                       settings.Text = "Find";
                                       settings.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
                                       settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = string.Format("function(s, e) {{ Click(); }}");
                                   }).GetHtml()
</div>
  @Html.DevExpress().PopupControl(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "pcSendProduct";
        settings.Width = 1050;
        settings.Height = 550;
        settings.HeaderText = "Plan Customer Interaction";
        settings.CloseAction = DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CloseAction.CloseButton;
        settings.Styles.Header.HorizontalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center;
        settings.Styles.Header.VerticalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.VerticalAlign.Middle;
        settings.Styles.Header.Font.Size = 10;
        settings.Modal = true;
        settings.ShowHeader = true;
        settings.ShowCloseButton = true;
        settings.CloseAction = DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CloseAction.CloseButton;
        settings.Left = 1245;
        settings.Top = 300;
        settings.Styles.ModalBackground.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        //settings.ContentUrl = Url.Action("SendProduct", "Home");
        settings.ShowLoadingPanel = true;
        settings.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = "OnBeginCallback";
    }).GetHtml()
```

SendProduct.cshtml

```
@model Demo.Models.Product
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SendProduct";
}

<h2>SendProduct</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Product</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductId)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

In above code when i click on button popup get open on brouser properly. but when I select popup header for changing the positions position or any reason popup containt will get dissapered or popup will show blank containt. When I deselect popup header popup containt view display on popup

Please please give me solution so that w hen user select popup header then popup containt will not become blank. Popup must show the view .

Comment: I copied your PopupControl setting in my project and did not find that behavior in Chrome and IE11. Do you register all DevExpress Styles and Scripts (Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets and GetScripts)?

Comment: Thank you replay By mistack I have commented settings.ContentUrl = Url.Action("SendProduct", "Home"); code into popup so please uncomment that code to open view into popup. After that You will get that blan containt condition

Comment: Now I reproduced it. I gave  explanation why this happen.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B95472) devexress team six year ago gave an explanation that it is impossible when you use ContentUrl property because the control render it in the iframe.

You can write view content in the ViewContext but your controller should return PartialView.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SendProduct(string rowId)
    {
        Product objProduct = new Product();
        return PartialView(objProduct);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendProduct(Product objProduct)
    {
        return PartialView(objProduct);
    }
 }
```

Popup settings

```
    settings.SetContent(() =>
    {
        ViewContext.Writer.Write((Html.Action("SendProduct", "Home").ToHtmlString()));
    });
    //settings.ContentUrl = Url.Action("SendProduct", "Home");
```